# Posting a file to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

:8000/upload:1 POST http://localhost:8000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

```
at createError (createError.js:17)
at settle (settle.js:19)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

While I'm uploading a file I'm getting this error, can anyone help for it.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to include your full code to get fast and appropriate responses !

Answer (score 0):

This error was because you did not handle the situation in the client when the server returns an [HTTP error 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors)

Actually, you have to check the server application, why it does not accept the upoplad, and only returns an error.